# How to show a custom filed in another page in different BLC?

Tags: acumatica

For example, I had created a custom field 'Brand' at detail of stock items in BLC 'InventoryItemMaint'.

But how to show the 'Brand' custom field at detail of sale order page? In different BLC 'SOOrderEntry'.

Comment: Check the data view of the Sales Order Lines if it contains Join to the Dac where you have added your custom field then just add your field from the Page Editor of the Customization, else change the data view to the one with join to your DAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you added your custom column to InventoryItem DAC like this:
[image]

First locate the other DAC where you want that custom field to appear. You can use Acumatica Inspect Element feature in Customization menu and then click on the grid where you want the field to appear:

[image]

This will tell you which DAC is bound to the grid, SOLine in this case:
[image]

SOLine contains a selector for the InventoryItem (SOLine.InventoryID). Add your custom field to SOLine InventoryItem selector so it becomes available in the selector window. You can do this by extending SOLine DAC, choose Add Field->Change Attributes of Base Field. The selector columns button will add stub code containing the existing columns, you can add your custom field in there:
[image]

This will make the custom column visible in Sales Order detail InventoryItem selector window:
[image]

Now you can add a new custom unbound (non-persisted) field to SOLine that will display your InventoryItem custom field using the SOLine InventoryItem selector:
[image]

Notice the PXFormula attribute that will fetch the custom field in InventoryItem DAC extension using SOLine.InventoryID selector:

```
[PXFormula(typeof(Selector<SOLine.inventoryID, PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItemExt.usrBrand>))]
```

Customize the Sales Order Entry screen to add the SOLine custom field to the detail grid:
[image]

Final result, custom field is displayed in Sales Order Entry screen detail grid:
[image]

Comment: Great example, and thx. This way seems be different to the Acumatica customization manual, it tells us to create or extend a data view in another BLC. Which way is better?

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish this. I've selected this method for a few reasons. First I assume the field is read-only in Sales Order screen so an unbound field is preferred. I also assume that having Brand in InventoryItem selector is desired to allow search of inventory items by brand. Redefining Acumatica base product DataView in Sales Order details to join it with InventoryItem would have worked too but if Acumatica changes the DataView in future versions you'll have to maintain it.

Comment: In the end this is mostly a matter of personal choice. The reasoning behind this is that you can easily 'extend' Acumatica DAC but you can't easily extend Acumatica DataView. With DataView you create new ones or redefine existing one. I avoid redefining if possible because Acumatica can change the DataView in future version and you won't pick up the changes if you have redefined it.

Comment: Thx a lot! Your answer is really helpful!

Comment: strange error after customization: [A]PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItemExt cannot be cast to [B]PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItemExt. Type A originates from 'RuntimeCode_1AB275DEA7DA7C22, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'LoadNeither' in a byte array. Type B originates from 'RuntimeCode_1AB275DEA7DA7C22, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'LoadNeither' in a byte array.

Comment: it happends randomly, do you know the reason? :p

Comment: Runtime source code in Asp.Net is compiled to "RuntimeCode_XXXXX.dll" on first load or when source code is  modified. It appears Asp.Net ended up with two copies of the same assembly in memory. I've seen that happen when you modify code while IIS is up and running. Command IISReset will unload all assemblies and recompile, after that a single copy should be in memory. There's various advice on the web that range from increasing memory available to the App pool to upgrading .Net.